# Is there a way to run a node dependency's postinstall script on install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, lifecycle

I'm trying to run my postinstall script every time someone runs npm install within their project where they have my package installed as a dependency.

Here's a minimal example of what my package's package.json looks like:

```js
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node -e \"try{require('./scripty')}catch(e){}\""
  }
}
```

For sake of verbosity, here's what `scripty.js` looks like:

```js
console.log('im a script');
```

Here's a minimal example of what someone's package.json would look like:

```js
{
  "name": "parent",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "example": "0.0.0"
  }
}
```

What I'm expecting to see is when the `parent` project runs `npm install`, in addition to installing all their dependencies, they will also see

```
im a script
```

logged in their terminal as a result of my `example` package's postinstall script.

As it stands, I'm not seeing anything on install. What am I missing?

Minimal repro/playground for the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-czrx3p?file=testy%2Fscripty.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postinstall` scripts may not run in Stackblitz due to their usage of Turbo, [as per their documentation](https://developer.stackblitz.com/platform/webcontainers/turbo-package-manager):

> Turbo **does not run install scripts** for your dependencies. This increases the security of the installation process, and prevents the spurious errors arising from the differences between the underlying platform (WebContainers) and a local environment.

Otherwise locally, the `postinstall` script *should* be running and you can check this by running `npm install --loglevel=verbose` or `npm install --foreground-scripts`. What you may be encountering is that `npm` prevents dependencies logging messages to the console, see [issue #3647 in the npm/cli GitHub repository](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3647) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realized that the Stackblitz example was a poor choice only after I had posted the question. I'll review that issue in the meantime.